# Blazor binding inconsistent behaviour

Tags: events, input, binding, blazor

I am building a blazor app (WASM) where I use some `<input>`'s with those inputs. to both I binded a variable, for easy overview I put that in the @code part of the (index)page.

on the second `<input>` I also put an onclick event, and in the onclick event I fill a third variable (ThirdText) with the first (FirstText).

When I start the application, and I click on the first `<input>`, and fill in some characters and then click on the second `<input>` the value of the third variable is still empty. But when I go back to the first, change a bit, and click on the second afterwards, it directly fills the NEW value.

The last bahaviour is what I also hoped for in the first situation.

Here I have my code in index.cs:

```
@page "/"

<h3>@FirstText</h3> <br/>
<h3>@SecondText</h3> <br/>
<h3>@ThirdText</h3> <br/>

<input @bind="FirstText" style="width:50%" /> <br/>
<input @bind="SecondText" @onclick="OnclickHandler" style="width:50%" /> <br/>

@code{
    private string FirstText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    private string SecondText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    private string ThirdText { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    void OnclickHandler(MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
    {
        ThirdText = FirstText;
    }
}
```

This code is an easy example, the real application has a lot more logic, but this is the base of my problem.

When I make the first box empty, and click on the second box, again it does not work as expected.

I already tried to first fill the 3th variable in oninitialised() , but then the first variable is also empty so, that does not work.

I know in javascript there is a simular problem, that is because the onclick is firstly called, and the onexit or other event you want to use on the exit of the first box is then forgotten. But in that case, it goes wrong al the time. I hope that blazor has a solution for this situation. Because it goes well in Blazor if the first input was already filled.

Comment: try: change `@bind` to `@bind-value` and add `@bind-value:event="oninput"` to the first input.

Comment: the first part did not help, the second part changed to the right idea but that means there is a update with each key stroke, and this is just a small example, the application is deemed to grow large.

Comment: I have now tried this in Blazor server, and there I found that the binding looks to work well, but the problem is the first time triggering of the onclick. So what I was hoping for is going well, but the trigger is another not so nice problem. found a lot of other topics about this, but the given solutions do not work so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You describe the current behaviour but at the same time you are a bit vague about what you expect. As far as I can tell the code does what you ask for.

And what do you expect (want) to happen when a User uses the Tab key to go to the next input? Is it about mouseclicking or about completing an input?

I think you should consider one of these two changes:

```
<input @bind="FirstText" style="width:50%" /> <br/>
<input @bind="SecondText" @onfocus="OnUpdateHandler" style="width:50%" />
```

or, and this seems more logical:

```
<input @bind="FirstText" @onblur="OnUpdateHandler" style="width:50%" />
<input @bind="SecondText"  style="width:50%" />
```

with

```
void OnUpdateHandler()
{
    ThirdText = FirstText;
}
```

If that doesn't work then be more specific: when/why do you want ThirdText  to mirror FirstText?

Comment: thx,  I think for inputs this a good solution, so I am a little step further. But for onclick on the buttons this is not yet a solution I think. I have some inputs but also several buttons with different onclicks, but I am studying all the different answers and suggestions, what is the best for the different parts.

Comment: There are no buttons in your question. But really, what can go wrong with a Button click?

Comment: For the original question/problem, this was the easiest workaround I think.  I learned a lot from all answers and suggestions, for the underlying problem I need to study some things more closely.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code is not working is because of the timing of the click event:

> If the button is pressed on one element and the pointer is moved
> outside the element before the button is released, the event is fired
> on the most specific ancestor element that contained both elements.
>
> click fires after both the mousedown and mouseup events have fired, in
> that order.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event)

Long story short, by the time `mouseup` (or even the `mousedown` for that matter) occurs, the layout has changed and input element has shifted outside of the range of the mouse pointer. For example, change your code to the following and you will see it works now because the elements do not shift:

```
<h3>AAA @FirstText</h3> <br/>
<h3>AAA @SecondText</h3> <br/>
<h3>AAA @ThirdText</h3> <br/>
```

The solution to your problem would depend on what you are trying to achieve, but the basic idea here is to not rely on click events when layout changes occur.

To really prove what is happening, in Chrome Dev Tools go to `Sources > Event Listener Breakpoints > Mouse > click` and make sure the checkbox is checked. After that, type something in the first input and then click the second input element. The click event **will** fire, however notice the event target in the below screenshot! It is not the input element but the parent element `<article>`. This proves that the click event was never dispatched to the input element because it is **not** underneath the mouse pointer when the mouseup event occurs.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are in the right direction. I'll vote you up. The user is not looking for solution, he's looking for explanation of this anomalous behaviour.

Comment: I see what you mean Jesse, but the code in the onclick was only to show me what happens with the binding variable. (because in Blazor WASM it is not yet possible to debug the code). I hoped that the onclick on the second box would not interfere with the first binding. But it looks like that it is not stable enoug for my wishes. Your point about the extra text before ther variable was very interesting, but makes it more mysterious for me :)

Comment: I did not test this yet, but lets asume there are a lot of <input> boxes in the form, and all have a binding variable or a field from a model. Then there is a button, and when you click on the button i want to be sure that the last input where you changed something also completed its binding to the variable. For now I have the possibility to bind on the oninput event which seems to work, but I hoped to avoid working on every keystroke.

Comment: @BlazorExperiencer: Do you know you can set breakpoints on properties and debug them? No need to create a handler for onclick.

Comment: @Jesse, Debugging does not work, I understood that is a problem for Blazor WASM.

Comment: @BlazorExperiencer: [It is possible to debug Blazor WASM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) so I don't understand what you mean. Are you using an older version of dotnet core?

Comment: @Jesse, no, visual studio 2022, .net 6.0, Blazer WASM project.

Comment: could not change it anymore: when I test it in a Blazer Server project, I can debug. I found out that the binding goes well (1 point for Microsoft) but that if the input was empty on entering, the onclick from the other input (or button) is not triggered.

Comment: @JesseGood - see my answer - the third attempt - that shows add or removing a single line of code changes the behaviour.  Does the mouse events explain the change in behaviour?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis: When you remove the single line of code, the elements do not shift down anymore so the click event occurs on the button. However when you add the line of code, the <h3> element becomes populated causing all the other elements to shift down and by the time you lift your finger off of the mouse the element is no longer under your mouse pointer causing the click event to occur on the parent element. To prove my point, try wrapping all the elements in a div like so `<div @onclick=SaveData>` and you will see the click event occur.

Comment: @JesseGood - spot on.  Which explains why it works if the `<h3>` element contains any text like `<h3>Your Name is @Name</h3>`.  Thank you.

Comment: @JesseGood, thanks so far, I now know what is the reason of the behavial. I will first look if I can work with this, if there are more buttons, all with their own onclick.

Answer (score 1):

#Third Answer:

Here's a test page to capture the problem in it's simplest form.

I've removed most of the original code and made it a simple data entry and save form - without using `EditForm`.

In the current configuration `SaveData` isn't called when you enter your name and click on the save button.

Comment out the line `<h3>@this.YourName</h3>` before the form and it now works.  Note there's a second `<h3>@this.YourName</h3>` below the form that has no impact.

Now change the line to:

```
<h3>Your name is: @this.YourName</h3>
```

and it works.

The answer lies in the answer provided by @JesseGood To quote his comment:

When you remove the single line of code, the elements do not shift down anymore so the click event occurs on the button. However when you add the line of code, the  element becomes populated causing all the other elements to shift down and by the time you lift your finger off of the mouse the element is no longer under your mouse pointer causing the click event to occur on the parent element.

```
@page "/"

@using System.Text

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

@*Comment out this line and the event triggers on first click*@
<h3>@this.YourName</h3>

<h3>Your Name is @DisplayName</h3>

<div class="m-2">
    Your Name: <input value="@this.YourName" @onchange=this.NameChange style="width:50%" />
</div>
<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="SaveData">Save</button> <br />
</div>

<h3>@YourName</h3>

<div>
    <pre>
        @log.ToString()
    </pre>
</div>
@code {
    private string YourName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    private StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
    private string DisplayName = string.Empty;
    
    void NameChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        this.YourName = e.Value?.ToString() ?? String.Empty;
        log.AppendLine("FirstChange Called");
    }

    void SaveData(MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
    {
        this.DisplayName = this.YourName;
        log.AppendLine("Value Saved");
    }
}
```

Follow on answer:

When you "bind" in Razor, the Razor compiler actually builds out the following code.  In the example I've just wired it up manually so I can output some debug code when the `onchange` event is raised.

```
__builder.OpenElement(15, "input");
__builder.AddAttribute(16, "style", "width:50%");
__builder.AddAttribute(17, "value", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.BindConverter.FormatValue(this.FirstText));
__builder.AddAttribute(18, "onchange", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder(this, __value => this.FirstText = __value, this.FirstText));
__builder.SetUpdatesAttributeName("value");
__builder.CloseElement();
```

> First and second Answer replaced

Comment: Thx Enet, I need to read your text very carefully, but 1 very little small point : me no she .. :)

Comment: MrC you removed the onclick from the second input (and placed it on the first), but that is the root of the problem. I know in javascript this is also a problem so I hoped that binding in Blazor would be a solution. The copying in the onclick wat just to test if the binding was completed, but that only sometimes seems to be the case, regarding the value in the variables. The strange thing for me is that something like : <h3>AAA @FirstText</h3> <br/> makes it work.

Comment: @BlazorExperiencer.  I didn't fully get your question first time round, so no problem.  I'll leave the answer as is for the moment.  I've just run some tests in Blazor Server and the behaviour as you described it doesn't happen the same way.  I see you're using WASM so I'll do some testing in that.  If no one has fully answered it in a few hours I'll have a look at the WASM version.  Got to go for now!

Comment: MrC, I have now tried it in Blazor Server Side also, and there it is exactly working how I hoped (or how I secretly expected). There debug is also working well, but when I put a breakpoint on the "        ThirdText = FirstText;" row, FirstText is already filled with the latest value. 'Sadly' I have to work with Blazer WASM in this case.

Comment: Sorry my last comment was not true, the first time I click in the second box, the onclick is not triggered. that is not good ..

Comment: @BlazorExperiencer - see my revised answer.  Everyone is trying to explain it but if you repeat the same sequence of events several times, the first sequence is different from the rest.  See my comment on raising it.  If you aren't sure how, I'll quite happily do so and add a link to the issue in this question.

Comment: Thx MrC, it seems most here agree there is something going wrong here. For myself I have only 1 button, to save the form. So I upgraded to the <EditForm> with a model, and that is working fine, the button added to the form does not have the same problem. But for my employer this is a problem, he has some buttons on the form not only for saving the data. And some other events on input boxes. So I will submit this as a bug to the microsoft team.

Comment: @BlazorExperiencer.  Post the issue number - I would like to see what is said.

Comment: enet, so if an input was empty before I entered the input, it is normal that a onclick on another element is not fired? while if the input was not empty earlier, the onclick works normally. this all while there is no real connection between the 2 elements. I think that is an bug, the onclick should always work or never (what would be another bug).

Comment: @enet, now I read your comments a little better, I do not think you got the right idea about the problem. yout talk about mouse up and down, but that should not be different between an (initialy) empty input and an filled input. If it was only the first time, then maybe you are right, but also if you clean the input and go to that input again, the onclick fails, and again the onclick of another element, that should not be the case.

Comment: @enet, I really don't understant your point of view. What about speed of light ? Why does the initial state of the input (empty or not empty) influence the onclick availability of another element? For me the "Blazor JS code is sinking the first click event." is exactly what happens.

Comment: @myself, now I made a mistake myself, I think blazor is sinking the onclick, but not because it is the first call, but because of a strange connection to a initial blank input.

Comment: @BlazorExperiencer: I have added a screenshot and explanation so hopefully it helps clear things up. The click event is being fired. The issue is the input element is not the target of the event because the layout has changed. In my example the target of the event is the `<article>` element which is the parent of the input element.

Comment: @BlazorExperiencer.  This intrigued me so I did some experimenting to try and isolate the problem.  See my Third Answer.

Comment: @enet - your comments have disappeared?  I was going to point out my third attempt at an answer in response to your comments.

Comment: Thx MrC, but there is still a strange part in your example:
 <input value="@this.YourName" @onchange=this.NameChange style="width:50%" />
you bind YourName to this input box, but then you do the same manualy:
this.YourName = e.Value?.ToString() ?? String.Empty; in the changed event

Comment: @BlazorExperiencer - see my comment in the answer.  I'm manually binding rather that letting Razor do the work.